# Return TRUE if counter is greater than 0?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

In PHP I am trying to return TRUE if $counter is greater than 0.  Would using a ternary operator work in this case.  Here is the original code:

```
if($counter>0){return TRUE;}else{return FALSE;}
```

could I condense that down to

```
return $counter>0?TRUE:FALSE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could condense it to `return $counter>0`

Because that is a Boolean expression itself.

Comment: I understand that 0 returns FALSE and 1+ return TRUE, but 0 !== FALSE and 1 !== TRUE

Comment: correct, however that's integers converting to booleans. The expression above is a straight up boolean expression

Comment: Thanks for providing this. Although some may find it easier to read or comprehend, it drives me nuts to see expressions that will return a boolean *anyways* have `TRUE` or `FALSE` explicitly tacked on. Like `if (1 == 1) { return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }`. Totally unnecessary. Just `return 1 == 1;`

Comment: Oh I understand, because $counter>0 is being tested and outputted as either TRUE or FALSE.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
return ($counter > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

If you like, yes you can!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could condense that, but you can sometime consider also that:

```
return is_int($counter) && $counter > 0;
```

This expression checks if it is greater than zero and in addition if `$counter` is integer.